# PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser count specific results?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Right now i am working around one PHP script based on http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
foreach ($html->find('li.tooltip') as $ul) {
    $id = $ul->id;
    $dt = "data-text";
    $dt = "data-text";
    $cid = "colvar-id";
    $datatext = $ul->$dt;
    $colvarid = $ul->$cid;
    $countN = count($id);
    $number = 1;
    $N = $i++;
    if ($N == "") {
        $N = 0;
     }
   }
?>
<?PHP echo "Result is: $countN"; ?>
```

This code is suposed to count the number of founded occurencies, but it displays nothing.

All i want is to count the founded occurencies and simply display the number of occurencies.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to learn to read your error logs.  If you did, you would see that you're missing a closing bracket `}`.

Comment: Your foreach loop should be closed before echo, shouldn't it?

Comment: Any reason you're using `SimpleHTMLDOM` instead of DOM & DOMXPath? The latter 2 are quite a bit faster.

Comment: Your variable should be called `$li` instead of `$ul`, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count()`:

```
$html = str_get_html(<<<EOF
<ul>
  <li>not a tooltip</li>
  <li class="tooltip">tooltip</li>
  <li class="tooltip">also a tooltip</li>
</ul>
EOF
);

echo count($html->find('li.tooltip'));
// 2
```